# File version control of binaries / executables that use resources metadata

Tags: version-control, executable, perforce, versioning

I have a large repository that builds many files such as dll:s and exe:s. These files build with resources information attached in the files with meta-information such as file version and company name etc.

If I wish to make an upgrade package of updates which includes only files that have been updated. I have to know whether any changes has been made to built binaries/executables. This causes two problems.

1. Version control in software like perforce handle source code great but source code in one project does not necessarily mean it doesn't end up in another projects dll.
2. As we build binaries with version information at the compilation the files "looks" different if they have different fileversion numbers but can be equal in the actual source code.

So basically, how do you manage file versions of binaries/executables in an automated process in order to determine which files that have been built are different from previous version?

One option could be to do the build process twice. Where the first build is with the old version number to compare and then build with the new version number and use. Does anyone have better suggestion or applications to recommend?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, my main suggestion would be to improve the version string generation.  If you can't determine from the version string what source the binary was built from, what's the point of even having a version string?  Ideally if the source doesn't change, the version string doesn't change either.

If it's not possible for your actual binaries to have useful version strings, my suggestion would be to embed that information (i.e. what source files were used and what the latest change to those source files was) in the change description when you submit the binaries -- that way you can at least look it up after the fact, and can use that information to compare binaries.

Comment: Well, yeah... That sounds great and I would love to do it like that but my question still stands as to how do I do that?

Comment: From the Perforce end, use `p4 changes -m1` to get the highest changelist for a path.  Using path+change for a version string means it'll always map perfectly to your source and it won't change if the source doesn't change.  Getting your build tool to use that useful version string instead of whatever pseudorandom number it's using now is a question for your build tool.  :)